# Asset field in Matrix not updating

Tags: matrix, assets

I have an Assets field in a Matrix column that has stopped updating. If you edit or delete the asset and save the entry, the entry will save successfully. However, if you reopen the entry (or view it) the image does not change. All other fields update successfully, but not the Asset field. This new behavior *roughly* coincides with updating to EE2.7.2, Matrix 2.5.8, and Assets 2.2.1.

Other odd behavior:

- It is not all Assets-in-Matrix fields -- other channels on the site use a similar Asset-in-Matrix construct and will update their Asset fields successfully.
- Duplicating the entry creates a new entry that will successfully update.

Are there any known issues with the updated plugins/EE build? Has anyone experienced the same thing? Any thoughts on how to further debug this issue?

Comment: **Temporary Fix** Downgrading Assets and Matrix seems to temporarily fix the problem. I downgraded Matrix to 2.5.5, then Assets to 2.1.3. Downgrading Matrix did not fix the issue, but after downgrading Assets I am able to edit the column again. That would imply that it's related to Assets 2.2.1 or to the combination of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating back to 2.2.1, running the following query will fix this:
UPDATE exp_assets_selections SET content_type = 'matrix' WHERE row_id > 0 AND (content_type = '' OR content_type IS NULL)

We're about to release Assets 2.2.2 that addresses this, but, while it's still not out, the query above should take care of your problem permanently. This only affects Matrix rows created before updating to Assets 2.2.1.

Comment: I updated back to 2.2.1, and ran the query `UPDATE exp_assets_selections SET content_type = 'matrix' WHERE row_id > 0 AND content_type = ''` -- this returned a "0 rows affected" result and testing shows the same behavior (matrix columns do not update on save). Thoughts?

Comment: Shanan, sorry, I totally botched up that query. I edited it to be correct now - give it a shot!

Comment: This successfully fixed the issue and the field updates correctly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, but found out that I did not have a column for 'content_type'. Once I added this column, Matrix/Assets began working correctly.